# Lack of active Google Cloud Function instances, each request ends with a timeout

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Recently I've encountered a problem with cloud functions.

As you can see on the screenshot the number of active instances has fallen to 0 even though new requests are still arriving. Each request ends with a timeout.

[image]

Functions look like this:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.matchmakingFun1 = functions.runWith({timeoutSeconds: 5, maxInstances: 1})
  .region('europe-west2').firestore 
  .document('Queue1/{player}') 
  .onCreate((snapshot:any, context:any) => {
    const roomCollection = 'Room1'; 
    const respCollection = 'Resp'; 
    const matchCollection = 'Match'; 
    const responseKey = snapshot.id;
    return db.runTransaction((trs: FirebaseFirestore.Transaction) => {
        return trs.get(db.collection(roomCollection).limit(1)).then((roomResult) => {
            if (roomResult.size == 1) { 
                const roomSnapshot = roomResult.docs[0];
                const matchId : string = roomSnapshot.id;
                trs.delete(roomSnapshot.ref);
                trs.set(db.collection(respCollection).doc(matchId), {num: 1, matchId: matchId});
                trs.set(db.collection(respCollection).doc(responseKey), {num: 2, matchId: matchId});
                trs.set(db.collection(matchCollection).doc(matchId), {seed: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000)});
            } else {
                trs.set(db.collection(roomCollection).doc(responseKey), {}); 
            }
            trs.delete(snapshot.ref);
     });
    });
  });
```

Function has `max-instaces=1` set because of the logic of the function, which doesn't allow concurrent calls.
But even if `max-instances` are set to 2 the problem still occurs.

Functions were working in this way since at least a year and there haven't been any problems with them before.

After deleting a function and creating it again everything works good for a small period of time.
Then usually after few hour number of instances again drops to 0 and each call ends with a timeout.
Message in function logs: Function execution took 5003 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'. No other info in logs.

Do you know any solution to this problem or workaround?
Any help appreciated. ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Function has max-instaces=1 set because of the logic of the function, which doesn't allow concurrent calls. But even if max-instances are set to 2 the problem still occurs.

From the best of my understanding and experience, the flag `max-instances` means slightly different thing, and it might not be used to achieve "concurrent calls". It is possible that at some point in time the number of parallel runnning instances of the cloud function is bigger than the `max-instances` value - see [Handling Traffic Spikes](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/max-instances#handling_traffic_spikes) - `... Cloud Functions may, for a short period of time, create more instances than the specified max instances limit`.

I would suggest to design and develop cloud functions in a such way that many of them can run in parallel, and handle concurency/sequencial requirements in some other way. In that case, you might be able to deploy the cloud function with a higher `max-instances` number, and the original issue may disapper.

Comment: I tried to test your idea, but problem still occures :(